# Set file name and extension when saving a video to Android's MediaStore

Tags: android, mediastore, scoped-storage

I need something really simple - I have an mp4 file that my app recorded and I want to insert it to the MediaStore to the user's video collection. Here is my code, including the recommended ways of dealing with the new Scoped Storage:

```
// fileToExpose is in internal storage with a name like video_1.mp4
fun copyVideoFileToMediaStore(fileToExpose: File, context: Context): Boolean {
    val resolver = context.contentResolver

    val volume = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY else MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL
    val videoCollection = MediaStore.Video.Media.getContentUri(volume)

    val videoDetails = ContentValues().apply {
        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileToExpose.name)
        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE, "video/mp4")
        put(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE, name)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
        }
    }

    val videoContentUri = resolver.insert(videoCollection, videoDetails) ?: return false

    resolver.openFileDescriptor(videoContentUri, "w", null).use { pfd ->
        pfd ?: return false
        fileToExpose.inputStream().use { input ->
            FileOutputStream(pfd.fileDescriptor).use { output ->
                input.copyTo(output)
            }
        }
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        videoDetails.clear()
        videoDetails.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
        resolver.update(videoContentUri, videoDetails, null, null)
    }

    return true
}
```

However, after this function call the file with name `video_1.mp4` becomes something like `1589077991588.3gp`, so both the name and the extension are different (my device is Android 9). `MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA` is deprecated. How can I fix this?

Comment: I do not get that result with [this similar code](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/blob/vFINAL/ConferenceVideos/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/conferencevideos/VideoRepository.kt#L75-96), when running on Android 10. In my case, it's videos rather than audio files. Are you getting your effect on Android 10 or older versions?

Comment: I'm getting that on Android 9, will update my question, thanks!

Comment: Personally, and FWIW, I would use the classic external storage filesystem I/O on older devices.

Comment: Seems like I also need to do that, I just watched too many Android Dev Summit and Google I/O videos and wanted to be completely up to date, maybe a bit too much.

Comment: You should use the .DATA column for below Q. You have no code for that.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party, but just stumbled accross this issue and was looking for an answer here. And while trying around, I think I found a solution: Updating the `MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME` *after* inserting the video data has done the trick (on Android 8, i.e.).

So while the above code worked for Android 10 and above, for Android 9 and below I've added to update the title after writing the content to the stream.

```kotlin
// [...] example as above, here we are after the `resolver.openFileDescriptor` section
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
    videoDetails.clear()
    videoDetails.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
    resolver.update(videoContentUri, videoDetails, null, null)
} else {
    // On Android <= 9 we need to update the display name after writing the data to ensure the DISPLAY_NAME is correctly set
    videoDetails.clear()
    videoDetails.put(MediaStore.Video.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, fileToExpose.name)
    resolver.update(videoContentUri, videoDetails, null, null)
}
```

So it seems that on Android < 10 devices the display-name and title get overwritten when inserting the data via the `contentResolver.openOutputStream`.