# MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME and MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH are not working on Android below Q (API 29)

Tags: android, kotlin

How can I set the location and name for my image as Android Q

The result in Android Q:

[image]

The result in Android below Q:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
private suspend fun createTempFileInSharedStorage(fileName: String): Any? {
    return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val collection = sdk29AndUp {
            MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
        } ?: MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
        val dirDest = File(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES,
            "app_name"
        )
        val date = System.currentTimeMillis()

        val contentValues = ContentValues().apply {
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "$fileName.jpg")
            put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_ADDED, date)
            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATE_MODIFIED, date)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "$dirDest${File.separator}")
                put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 1)
            }
        }

        val imageUri = contentResolver.insert(collection, contentValues)


        return@withContext imageUri?.let { uri ->

            contentValues.apply {
                clear()
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.IS_PENDING, 0)
                } else {
                    put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "$fileName.jpg")
                }
                contentResolver.update(uri, contentValues, null, null)
                return@let imageUri
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I have done:

- Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65627697/9211363), updating `DISPLAY_NAME` after inserting isn't work.

Comment: Have you tried to add it to path? Like that `            put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "$dirDest${File.separator}${fileName}.jpeg")`

Comment: My app crashed when I added  put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "$dirDest${File.separator}") on Android below Q
(NullPointerException)

Comment: Maybe try answer from there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61786785

Comment: I have updated my post. It's still not working